# Applying Voter automatically to several methods in a controller

Tags: php, symfony, authorization, symfony-3.3

I have a voter that checks if user can edit a document, the rules are either user owns document or user is a super admin, to check ownership of document the document Entity first has to be fetched. This I managed without any problem.

But it seems that I have to add:
`$this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('edit', $doc);`
to about 7 methods in my controller, is there a more efficient way of doing this?

I thought of using Kernel Event, but putting this check in event subscriber doesn't do much, because I don't see any way to influence further code execution. And if I throw uncaught exception whole Symfony will crash. No matter what I do, the called method will be executed... But then I might as well just edit every method.
I don't want to repeat this piece of code everywhere but it seems I don't have another option.

Comment: The obvious question is why do you need seven methods just to edit an object.  Seems excessive.  More to the point perhaps, a controller listener can change which controller action is called so it could easily redirect a denied access to put up a "nope nope nope" page or whatever it is you want.  Finally, Symfony does not crash when an exception is thrown.  Take a look at [exception handler subscribers](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html#working-with-the-kernel-exception-event) to see how to handle these sorts of things.

Comment: This document is part of complicated process of returning items from shop to supplier, to complete this there are many steps involved(finance,locating it in warehouse, shipping it out, confirmation that it was received... and some more). Between some of them Category Manager must review changes, for each of the steps there is an action and we need to be sure that owner or super admin is approving it.

By crash I meant the "There has been an exception" it shows an error screen, that completely differs from interface and is not something with which user can cope.

Comment: Right but as the link I gave you shows, you can intercept the exception and display whatever you want.  Keep in mind that only category owners can even see the review screen so anytime an access is denied it must be a hacking attempt.  No real need to present an overly friendly interface to a hacker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will depend on where you are getting `$doc`. You can put a [@Security](http://symfony.com/doc/3.3/security/voters.html) annotation (or `@IsGranted("do-stuff-with-doc")`) onto the class itself to allow, or deny, access to all the actions in it (this does presume that just the 7 actions you want to protect are in the same class).

With a [voter](http://symfony.com/doc/3.3/security/voters.html) checking access for the current user on the permission called *"do-stuff-with-doc"*, since that will also be a service, it's got access to all the other services you care to inject, and the $request that is about to be injected into the appropriate actions (via `RequestStack $reqstack; $currRequest = $reqstack->getCurrentRequest();`). In the current-request are the action's parameter, which would either have the $doc, or enough information you could probably get it.

From that, or other services you can auto-wire (or manually define to inject) into the voter, it's up to you to how, or why a user has access to whatever.

```
class DoDocStuffVoter extends Voter
{
    public function __construct(RequestStack $reqStack)
    {
        $this->reqStack = $reqStack;
        // and other services you want to add
    }

    public function supports($attribute, $subject)
    {
        return $attribute === 'do-stuff-with-doc';
    }

    protected function voteOnAttribute($attribute, $object, TokenInterface $token): bool
    {
        $user = $token->getUser(); 
        $request = $this->reqStack->getCurrentRequest();

        dump($user, $request);
        die;

        // does someone with this request get access to doc?
        return $this->userHasAccessToDoc($user, $request);  
    }
}
```